# graying out a checkboxes after slecting multiple options and clicking submit

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a multiple checkboxes making up a list. I want a user to be able to select as many as they wish, to click a submit button after filling in their details and for the selected checkboxes to now be grayed out so someone else visiting the page will only be able to select from the available remaining checkboxes.

I'm assuming I'd need to keep a database to keep track of the user's details and their selection as well as the remaining checkboxes still avaialble?
Would that mean php is the best option or is there another easier / more efficient way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's lots of ways to implement this. Even without a "database". Do you have a code attempt?

Comment: Hey GetSet. 
I don’t yet. If I had to code something it would be what I described above. I wanted to get feedback before starting to see if there’s a more efficient way that I hadn’t thought of. 
How would you implement this without a dB?

Comment: Well you need a way to override on the 1st arrived "user" of said form to reach the back-end execution; even if simultaneous entries are rare. However, in terms of "without" a "database", one way would be to have a text file, that stored current state of available textboxes: e.g. `1=available,2=taken,3=available` etc. As mentioned, lots of ways to even format this text file. This is why a code attempt helps. Without a code attempt, the only solutions are code designs, which in fact may not be desirable for your own thought process or coding style. Just ideas.  Ideas arent solutions exactly.

Comment: Thanks GetSet. 
The reason why I thought a database was because the user will be entering their name and email as well as selecting the checkboxes. 
Thanks for the explanation although still not sure how to convert from a text file to a list of checkboxes but I’ll think about how and try come up with a code attempt!

Comment: A database makes sense. The "someone else visiting the page will only be able to select from the available remaining checkboxes" makes a database even more viable because you'd have less concurrency logic. You'd still might need "some" concurrency logic in place for that though too (e.g. sqlite). A "text file" has advantage here (at least in the beginning) as you need not get too side tracked with the db mechanics.

Comment: A db is preferred tho. You could have a 'users' table of course. Store each user's checkbox selections. If I read correctly and you want only checkboxes that no other user has selected, query that for the "greyed-out" boxes. Again, lots of ways to implement something.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Yeah thats the line of thinking I had as well :)